# Two Terraform Resources referencing eachother

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

The goal is to set up two services, an [Azure function app](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/function_app.html) and a [Cosmos DB](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/cosmosdb_account.html). The Cosmos DB should allow traffic only from the function app, and the function app should use the key of the Cosmos DB to access it.

**Relevant Terraform code**

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "cosmosdb_account" {
  ...
  ip_range_filter     = azurerm_function_app.function_app.possible_outbound_ip_addresses
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "function_app" {
  ...
  app_settings = {
    key = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb_account.primary_master_key
  }
}
```

**Error**

> `Error: Cycle: azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb_account, azurerm_function_app.function_app`

Is there any way to do this without null_resources or weird hacks?

Comment: I'm afraid you can achieve it without other means. The `azurerm_cosmosdb_account` and `azurerm_function_app` do not have separated resources to set the `ip_range_filter` and `app_setting` in Terraform.